# How do I open a directory with CreateFile()

Tags: winapi

SetFileTime says that it must be given a handle opened with CreateFile referring to a file or directory. But what are the proper parameters to open a **directory** with CreateFile ?

Comment: `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` *You must set this flag to obtain a handle to a directory*

Comment: There's a section titled *"Directories"* in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew). Did you not read it or did you but it didn't answer all your questions. In case of the latter, what is the specific question you have?

Comment: Thanks, @RbMm, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS was what I looked for !!!